# how to take data from database table partially and put it to the list using java?

Tags: java, sql, database-connection

Let say i have millions of records in the oracle table and I want to put every record to the java list. At the end I want to compare this list with another one. Unfortunately I cannot do this at once because the table is to big and I don't have enough memory to store such a huge list. My idea is to do this partially.
For example take each time 500000 records from the table and save it in the list, compare with another one and then clear it. 
So for the first time a will take records from DB with id 1-500000, then 500001-100000 and so on. 
But the question is how to do this? Without this requirement I would do something like this:

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM myTable";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
// how many columns it the table
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (rs.next()) {
              for(int i=0;i<columnsNumber;i++){

                String row= ""
                String row= row + " "+ rs.getString(i);

            }

 list.add(row);
}
```

But how to do this with WHERE condition in SELECT query
First do this for query with WHERE id<500000
then WHERE id between 500001 and 100000 and so on?

Comment: How about adding the `WHERE id<500000` to the `query` string? How about reading a tutorial on using JDBC?

Comment: @Andreas I know I can add just WHERE clause but I don't know how to parametized it and make it in a loop and what to do with the last part where I divide it on 50000 records but I have 130000 records all thogether.
I read a tutorial but I didn't find an answer on my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can query the db for total number of rows in the table, then create your query with next offset like below:

```
Integer limit = 50000;
Integer offset = 0;
String query= "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM myTable";
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
Integer total = rs.getInt("total");
Integer itrCount = (int) Math.ceil((double) total/limit);

for(int i=0; i< itrCount; i++){
    String query1 = "SELECT * FROM myTable limit " + limit + " offset " + offset;
    Statement st1 = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(query1);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd =  rs1.getMetaData();
    int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (rs1.next()) {
      for(int i=0;i<columnsNumber;i++){
            String row= ""
            String row= row + " "+ rs1.getString(i);
       }

       list.add(row);
    }        

    offset += limit;

    // do something with your list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I have to ask. Why do you have to gather this into a `List` first? Can you compare the items one at a time? Since you are suggesting looking at arbitrary subsets, that suggests to me that you're looking at the individual items and not the list as a whole. If that's the case, then I'd recommend looping over the entire table and processing one record at a time. If that's not the case, then I don't think breaking it out into chunks like this actually does you any good.

Anyway, I'll show you a few ways that you can split this out as you asked. You can probably just let the `ResultSet` interface do the dirty work for you. Most implementations would leave the data on the database and not load it into the JDBC client's memory until it's needed. I would try it that way first. Then you just do something like this:

```
int limit = 50000;
String sql = "select * from myTable";
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
int columnCount = rs.getResultSetMetaData().getColumnCount();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (rs.next()){
  if (list.size() == limit){
     processList(list);
     list = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
  StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i=1; i <= columnCount; i++){ 
    row.append(rs.getString(i));
  }
  list.add(row.toString());
}
processList(list);
```

So this consumes 50000 results from the `ResultSet` and processes them before continuing with more records.

This can also be done by added some parameters to the query. Exact details depend on which database and version you are using. Oracle 12 has a `fetch first` and `offset` clauses that can do what you need. Prior to that, you have to use rownum. And you have to be careful or it might not actually do what you think. Namely, you have run a query with an `order by`, put the `rownum` on those results, and finally filter the records in a `where` clause. The SQL looks like this:

```
select * from
  (select ordered.*, rownum as r
   from (select * from myTable order by ... ) ordered
  ) where r >= 0 and r < 50000
```

This guarantees that the rows are ordered before the `rownum` is applied to them and that the `rownum` is generated before they are filtered. Without those steps, you could get the same rows every time you run the query or you could miss rows. In Java, it would look something like this:

```
int batchSize = 50000;
String sql = "select * from "
  + " (select ordered.*, rownum as r "
  + " from (select * from myTable order by ... ) ordered "
  + " ) where r >= ? and r < ? ";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
int lowerBound = 0;
boolean keepTryingQuery = true;
while (keepTryingQuery){
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  upperBound = lowerBound + batchSize;
  ps.setInt(1, lowerBound);
  ps.setInt(2, upperBound);
  ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
  int columnCount = rs.getResultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
  while (rs.next()){
    StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++){
      row.append(rs.getString(i));
    }
    list.add(row.toString());
  }      
  processList(list);
  keepTryingQuery = list.size() > 0;
  lowerBound = upperBound;
}
```

This one runs a SQL statement that returns a subset of the table. Then it fills all of those results into a list. Once the list is full, then it does whatever needs to be done with it. After that, it moves on to the next range of the query. It just keeps increasing the bounds until the query doesn't return rows. The real key is that it shows the mechanics of setting parameters on a `PreparedStatement`. You could also do like Sanju suggests and run a separate count query to explicitly define the bound. This one can be simplified quite a bit if there's a numeric primary key on the table. Then you can just do something like `select * from myTable where primaryKey >= ? and primaryKey < ?`. You won't get exactly the same batch size in every one but then you don't have to mess around with `rownum` at all. Likewise, on Oracle 12 you can do something like `select * from myTable order by ... offset ? rows fetch next ? rows` to avoid dealing with `rownum`.

Both approaches have some drawbacks. With the first, I'd be nervous about leaving the `ResultSet` open while processing the `List`. In the second one, you have to get the details just right or you won't process each row exactly once. Both are vulnerable to modifications to the table while you are processing. In the first, you might just create a deadlock for somebody else. With the second, you'd lose the guarantee that you actually processed the whole table.

Personally, I'm not sure I'd use either approach. **I'd strongly consider using Spring Batch for this.** It separates the business logic from the mechanics of the I/O. It also has built-in classes that automatically handle many of the concerns with this. If that's overkill, I'd at least declare more classes and interfaces to split this out a bit more. Code that's comparing the data shouldn't know where it came from. Code that's producing it shouldn't know where it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you clarify in the first approach what processList(list) is?  And as sb variable you mean list? I'm confused a little bit.

Comment: The `processList` is just an imaginary method for whatever else you need to do with it. And it looks like I used the wrong name for the sb.append. I'll fix it.